# ReactJS race between componentWillMount and render functions

Tags: ajax, reactjs

```
export class Dashboard extends React.Component<DashboardProps, IMonthlyCommission>{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        request.get("AffiliateCommissionStatement/GetCommissionDetails").send().end((err, res) => {
            var data: IMonthlyCommission = res.body.Commissions;
            this.setState(data);
        });
    }

    render() { 
       return <div>{this.state[0]}</div> ;
    }
}
```

Inside render, `this.state[0]`  is null since the ajax call in `componentWillMount` is ASYNC.

How do I create a depenedncy between `render` and the ajax  `end` function.
So this way I won't get null exception/

Thanks

Comment: You don't; you handle the case where it hasn't loaded the data yet.

Comment: @DaveNewton, I don't understand. please explain. thanks

Comment: You actually need to handle 3 different cases inside render: pending data (show spinner or nothing), data loaded successfully, error occured while loading data.

Comment: I mean exactly that--it's going to render when React wants it to render. If your data hasn't loaded yet, that's too bad. You need to handle rendering before data has loaded, e.g., a spinner, a loading message, nothing, placeholder animations, whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You could make your render method handle the case where the data is not there yet:

```
render() {
  if (!this.state.data) 
    return <div>Loading...<div>

  return <div>{this.state.data[0]}</div>
}
```

Comment: if (!this.state.data) 
    return <div>Loading...<div>
if (!this.state.data[0])
    return <div>Data not found...<div>